# add result/count if is_product_tag - woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi I'm customizing a wordpress theme which did not have breadcrumbs and sort by functionality on the tag archive pages. i've found a workaround with some custom css/php to make this work but I'm struggling with the **result/count loop**.

So far I've added following to their custom category.php in my child themes folder which is working fine:

```
<div class="brtags">
<div class="page-title-inner flex-row  medium-flex-wrap container">
<div class="flex-col flex-grow medium-text-center">
<?php if(is_product_tag()) woocommerce_breadcrumb(); ?>
</div>
<div class="flex-col medium-text-center form-flat">
<?php if(is_product_tag()) woocommerce_catalog_ordering(); ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions on what code to add in order for the result count also to be visible only when on a tag archive page?

Comment: Figured it out by adding <?php if(is_product_tag()) woocommerce_result_count(); ?>

Comment: you can add your solution as an answer as well. it might be more future proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out by adding

```
<?php if(is_product_tag()) woocommerce_result_count(); ?>
```